# Assigning coefficients summing to 1 to values of points based on distance

Tags: geometry

I'm searching for a method to assign coefficients summing to one based on relative distance of points from the origin, with the closest distances having the largest coefficients.

For example, if I had points x1, x2, and x3 with distances of 1, 10, and 20, I would want them assigned coefficients of x1 > x2 > x3 with x1 + x2 + x3 = 1, x1 being on the order of 10 * x2 and 20 * x3, and x2 being on the order of 2 * x3.

Even just a name of the sort of thing I'm looking for would be helpful, as I'm not sure what this would even be called.

Comment: Let the coefficients be proportional to $1/r$, sum them all up and divide each by this sum.

Comment: What is r in this case?

Comment: Ummm... relative distance.